# jpa find problem

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

the find method does not return the latest version of an object.
somewhere in my code I find an object, change it, merge it and commit my changes. In the database the changes are made but in another function I find this object and my changes are not there.
I've checked race-conditions with the result that there are no race-conditions.
I've checked if there are duplicates of this object or different ids but that works fine.

Does anyone have an idea?

db: mysql
persistence: eclipselink

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets from the part where you commit your change and the part where you retrieve the stale entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an EntityManager already open while another EntityManager does the merge/commit?  The stale entity might be coming from an EntityManager that is not yet sync'ed with the changes committed to the database in another EntityManager elsewhere.

Try calling the `flush()` method on the EntityManager that needs to be sync'ed.

Answer (score 0):

jim is right. I've got two EntittyManager which are out of sync. My solution is now to have only one entity-manager. Is there a nice solution to get both manager synced because I have two threads and it can be possible that both threads wants to begin a transaction at the same time for instance which might be a problem...